# Available JAXB Classes for JIRA API?

Tags: java, api, jaxb, jira

I am looking for **JAXB classes** (XML binding for Java) to represent the [JIRA REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/) - preferably for the current version (6.1.4, though our atlassian.net site says JIRA v6.2-OD-03), although I can update an older version as needed.

*Background*:

I'm working on a simple Java service that searches JIRA for issue details and compiles custom reports for our team.  We have a quick 'n dirty set of JAXB classes, but they're both cluttered and incomplete.  The full set of things returned is heavily nested JSON and not trivial to represent with JAXB.  I'd love to have an existing implementation (official or otherwise) to help minimize my effort.

Searching for info on this is overly cluttered with info on using JAXB in a JIRA plugin, which is entirely unrelated my issue but apparently much more commonly done.

Comment: You could always build a JIRA Plugin to have it generate the report for you from within JIRA, then you wouldn't have to use the REST API and convert items to and from Objects.

Comment: I may suggest the plugin route if we decide that the chart I made needs anything further.  The hope was that I could quickly throw together a simple web service and page to make a burnup chart using the JIRA API.  However, it ended up being a few days worth of effort due to 1) inconsistencies within the JIRA API, and 2) the JRJC libraries being 2 major versions out of date (v4) compared to JIRA (v6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching for something else entirely, I came across the [JIRA REST Java Client](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JRJC/Home) page.  It has almost exactly the classes I'm looking for, though I'll have to modify them to work with JAXB and not require some of their project dependencies.

Comment: It turns out that the JIRA REST Java Client is woefully out of date - currently 2 major versions behind the actual JIRA API.  I have converted it to use JAXB, cut out the client code (I only wanted the XML representation), and dropped all external dependencies (except javax.*).  However, I only updated (from API v4 to v6) the few areas that I was using.  If anyone has interest, I can probably provide my source code.